# Using functions to manage relationships in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am working (for the first time) with Backbone.js in creating a reasonably simple application. I am currently working with two entities that have a one-to-many relationship:

- Project: has many groups
- Group: belongs to one project

I looked at a few different ways of representing relationships between models, from Backbone's own recommendations to Ligament to Backbone-relational. However, I eventually settled on using simple function calls. For example, within my 'Project' model, there's a function called groups():

```js
groups: function() {
  return new Collections.Groups(groups.where({project_id: this.get('id')}));
}
```

And within the Group model:

```
project: function() {
  return projects.where({id: this.get('project_id')})[0];
}
```

This allows me to do things like:

```
var foo = new Project();
var foo_groups = foo.groups();
foo_groups.at(0).get('name');

var bar = new Group();
var bar_project = bar.project();
bar_project.get('name');
```

To me, the tradeoff here is the overhead of maintaining up-to-date relationships (when using something like backbone-relational) versus the processing time used calling the 'groups()' function each time you want to get a project's groups.

Can anyone advise me on any pitfalls I may encounter down the road as I build out more relationships in this way, perhaps recommending a better solution (other than the extensions mentioned above)? The application will eventually have about 6 entities with a variety of one-to-many and many-to-many relationships

Comment: i guess we're on same boat; spent hours to find righteous and easiest way to deal with hierarchies between the models. I hope somebody answers here..

Comment: have you found your time-proven favourite solution?

Comment: I'm currently using a method written about here: http://slashhashbang.com/2011/10/lightweight-relation-modeling-with-backbone/. It overrides 'set' and makes it very easy to handle simple top-down relationships

Answer (score 0):

#### Project.groups

I have an implementation of what I call `AutoUpdatedCollection`.

I use it in the scenario you have a *shared Collection* which contains every Model of one class, and this Collection is used to populate *sub-Collections* those have to be *updated* when the shared Collection is updated.

Check the implementation of the [Backbone AutoUpdatedCollection](https://gist.github.com/3288350).

Following your example I suppose there is a *common/shared Collection* called `window.groups`, then I'll implement `Project` Model like this:

```
// code simplified and no tested
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.groups =
      new App.AutoUpdatedCollection({
        name:             "Project-" + this.id + "-groups",
        sourceCollection: window.groups,
        filterField:      "project_id",
        filterValue:      this.id
      }).filteredCollection;

    this.groups.on( "add", this.addGroup, this );
    this.groups.on( "remove", this.removeGroup, this );
  }
});
```

Maybe is not as simple as this, if you have any problem let me know.

#### Group.project

I'd just initialize the `Group.project` attribute in the `Group.initialize()`:

```
var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
  this.project = window.projects.where({id: this.get('project_id')})[0];
});
```